# Using pyglet, twisted, pygtk together in an application

Tags: networking, asynchronous, twisted, pygtk, pyglet

I am making an app, that lets you play music synchronously on different systems. For the project, I have decided to use twisted, PyGtk2, Pyglet. I am confused on how should the main loop be run. Should i run pyglet's loop in a separate thread or should i implement a new reactor integrating twisted, pygtk2, pyglet. Will the performance suffer if i try to integrate three loops together?

Answer (score 4):

I used https://github.com/padraigkitterick/pyglet-twisted when playing with pyglet and twisted, and it worked for my toy cases. Good starting point, anyway.

The above is a new reactor based on ThreadedSelectReactor.

It's not clear to me what the composition of all three would look like...

Answer (score 2):

Twisted already has a solution for integrating with gtk: 
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html#core-howto-choosing-reactor-gtk

I'm not familiar with pyglet but if it has a main loop like GTK then both of your ideas seem feasible. You could also look into how twisted implements the GTK integration explained in the link above and try to replicate that for pyglet.