# How to integrate Pyglet with Twisted/Asyncio?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, twisted, pyglet

How can I integrate a Python-Pyglet game with either Twisted or Asyncio?

I was going to ask a more general question, like "How can I add networking to a Python-Pyglet game?", but when doing any kind of web-search, "all roads lead to Twisted", anyway. However, both Pyglet and Twisted have their own event-loop, and it's not clear how they can be integrated. None of the other answers I've found, have more detail than "use Twisted", either.

Twisted does have a list of libraries it integrates with, including GUI ones like WxPython, but Pyglet is not on the list. I read one article that said Pyglet was going to be integrated with Twisted - from 2008, so I'm not holding my breath.

There is a `pyglet-twisted` library, but it's five years old on Github. There's no version information, but the sample-code has Python-2 print statements, so I'm guessing it's out-of-date. [Using Pyglet and Twisted together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27851866/78409)

Same for Asyncio, which I also looked at - it has its own event-loop. Although Pyglet docs do have some information about doing a custom event-loop, I'm not sure how well it plays with others. I'd actually prefer using Asyncio, if it's feasible to get them to play nicely together.

Comment: I'm not sure that all roads lead to Twisted: asyncio has been the kid on the block for all new networking code for several years now. pyglet doesn't seem to natively support asyncio integration, but you can run the asyncio event loop in a separate thread using `loop.run_forever()` and use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) to submit tasks to the event loop.

Comment: @user4815162342 yes, that was mainly a joke (although Twisted was mentioned everywhere), and why I also said I'd prefer Asyncio. Basically, whichever one will work best (easiest) with Pyglet. And if you have working code that runs Pyglet + Asyncio together, that sounds like an Answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have working code, otherwise I would have written an answer. :) I think the best way is to run the two event loops in separate threads and communicate using `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()` and thread-safe queues. Unfortunately Pyglet's event loop doesn't seem to document how to wake it up from another thread, or even how to add an arbitrary file descriptor, which is a common technique to implement such a wakeup. If you can find out this information, I can help you with the integration.

Comment: The alternative is to combine the two event loops in the same thread, choosing one as the driver, and using ticks to run individual "iterations" of the other. While some people have used such approach to integrate asyncio and Tkinter, and the Pyglet event loop seems to have [limited support](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/eventloop.html#dispatching-events-manually) for being driven from the outside, it's not something I'd recommend for production. Running an event loop in a mode that is totally different from how it's normally run is probably asking for trouble.

Comment: `pyglet.app.platform_event_loop` have [post_event](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/app.html?highlight=thread#pyglet.app.PlatformEventLoop.post_event). It is thread-safe method that it seems can be used to communicate with Pyglet from asyncio thread.

Comment: @ArtemiyRodionov That's interesting. But I'm not sure what to pass as the `dispatcher` parameter. For communication with a foreign event loop I think you'd need something like [`call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe), which lets you run an arbitrary function within the event loop thread without much ceremony.

Comment: [Something experimental was added in a recent release of pyglet](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/7df9ee869242f482579f1aa0ed5c61e39c4a444f/pyglet/experimental/net.py#L55)

Answer (score 0):

You could get a quick win by basing code off of [`pigtwist`](https://github.com/padraigkitterick/pigtwist/blob/master/pigtwist/pygletreactor.py) and convert Py2 to Py3 syntax. Which doesn't look like a whole lot. There's also the [`crochet`](https://github.com/itamarst/crochet) package that runs `twisted` in it's own thread, which you could run the network stack on. I also found [this example](https://groups.google.com/g/pyglet-users/c/xGlu-niqSIA/m/gVmNg7q_BwAJ), which uses a coiterator approach.

Hopefully `pyglet` will incorperate `asyncio` into itself given that it's a pure Python library. Maybe file a ticket with the team?

Comment: maybe worth explaining here that the general idea here is that to integrate two different event loops, you need a reactor such as pigtwist (typo in your link to it).

Comment: Ah, the joys of open-source - all too often the answer to a question is, "just patch the repo". :) And given that the last article I read about `pyglet` incorporating `asyncio` was from 2008, I'm thinking it's not a priority.